# Why export MaterialModule

Tags: angular

This [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-paginator-with-cards-localreadydata?file=app/app.module.ts),

**app.module.ts** `export class MaterialModule {}` and 2nd `@NgModule` does `imports[ MaterialModule, ]`. It doesn't `import {MaterialModule}` at the top, so where does it get it from and why export it as a class? (rem-out both caused err)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The purpose of `MaterialModule` is to re-export only the `@angular/material` modules which are used.
2. `MaterialModule` is declared in the same file as the `AppModule` class - something which is not very common in real-world apps. The Angular style guide recommends having only one `NgModule` per file.
3. `MaterialModule` is exported with `export class MaterialModule {}` because otherwise the Angular compiler will consider it private and won't include it in the final build.

You can simplify the code by omitting the `MaterialModule` declaration and just include the used `@angular/material` modules in `AppModule`'s imports:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    // @angular/material modules
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatPaginatorModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: so it's re-packaging a subset of `material` and under the name `MaterialModule` (diff from the original `@angular/material`, and exported to itself. Tried suggested, works out great!